# Flutter set Future List to null

Tags: flutter, null, future

I use a future List in flutter inside a State class, but setting it to null is always giving me an exception.

```
Future<List<String>> myList;
```

Inside Method:

```
myList = Future(null);
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GbNp.png)

What's the correct way of deleting all entries of a Future-List?

Comment: Why do you have a Future<List<String>>?  And, why are you trying to modify a Future value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `myList = []` or possibly `myList = Future.value([])` should do. But why would you want to remove a list like that?

Comment: In my case, I'm getting data from the network and then doing further processing on the data before returning the data in the future....and while, writing this comment, it occurred to me that its not necessary to do this because I'm processing "before" returning the future. So I guess false alarm? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯